# Using an attribute to prematurely return from a method

Tags: c#, attributes, custom-attributes

Is it possible to make an attribute that checks a condition and then based on that condition either stop the decorated method from executing or let the decorated method continue on executing?

And now the obvious question. If so, how? If not, then is there a work around worth checking out?

The overall goal of this attribute is to, in ASP.NET MVC, check if a user is authorized and either return a particular `JsonResult` (defined in the attribute) if they aren't authorized or let the decorated method keep on executing. The obvious problem I see with this being possible is if the controller action is of a different type than `ActionResult` or `JsonResult` that there exists the possibility of a runtime error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your particular situation, you can use an ASP.NET MVC *filter* to do what you need.  Have your attribute extend [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute_methods.aspx).

```
public class MustHaveFooAccessAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // Return true or false after checking authorization
    }
}
```

Comment: So after I return false from there how would I return JSON with an error?

Comment: You could override HandleUnauthorizedRequest

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using attributes - attributes are resolved at compile time. They do not get executed during runtime.

Specific behavior that attributes "control" is managed through reflection.