# Custom Attribute Method Level Authorization

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

I'm trying to use custom attributes to implement authorization permissions to execute a method. Here is what I have right now (i'm just starting on custom attributes):

```
[RequiredUserPermissions(UserPermissions.CanLoginViaSite)]
internal static bool HasDesiredPermissions()
{   
    //Execute body here if the attribute decorated permissions exist
    //for current user tracked as this._user (with permissions as
    //this._user.UserPermissions (of type UserPermissions (an enum))
}

//Custom attribute class
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
internal sealed class RequiredUserPermissionsAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly UserPermissions _requiredPermission;

    public RequiredUserPermissionsAttribute(UserPermissions requiredPermission)
    { this._requiredPermission = requiredPermission; }

    public UserPermissions RequiredPermissions
    { get { return _requiredPermission; } }
}
```

The closest question that I've found on stackoverflow is [Using an attribute to prematurely return from a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688790/using-an-attribute-to-prematurely-return-from-a-method). The answer would have been perfect if I was using asp.net mvc framework but unfortunately I'm in a WCF Service right now and implementing whole Authorization layer beyond the simple database login that I have right now (through a WCF Method call) is not feasible right now from timeline perspective.

I believe [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) is probably the best option but again not a feasible option right now. Am I stuck here? Should I just go back to doing this through Methods that take enum and return bool. I am happy to learn detailed / complex stuff if it will let me implement this functionality through custom attiributes.

Any help with how I can go about this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it could apply to your case, but if you are writing a WCF service, why don't you use role base authorization directly from the framework? It's either role or claim based, and for the simplest cases you can define it by means of attributes.
The roles could be defined either via a [Custom Principal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702720.aspx) or simply by using the standard role providers defined in the framework.

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = 'LoginViaSiteVisitors')]
internal static bool HasDesiredPermissions()
{
   //....
}
```

Comment: Because of the way its setup right now, the user logged in through framework is either non-existent (service running in anonymous mode) or a different user than the one that will be actually logging in through Service.LoginUser() method (on whom these permissions are to act) -- But thanks for the input :)

Comment: Can't you define your principal in Service.LoginUser() and set it as the current Principal? Something like `Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(user, password), roles);`? I think that this might work.

Comment: Hmm I didn't think of that. I'm about to rush out of office now, but when I come back on monday, I'll try to give it a go like that.I'll post back once I've had a go at this. Many thanks for the idea.

Comment: sorry about the delay in my response. I think this is the right route I have to follow. I've got a class deriving from `GenericIdentity` overriding `IsAuthenticated`. I can build custom principals with my roles defined in. All good thus far. My only concern now is, how can i stop the user from just building a GenericIdentity and passing that into principal with forged roles instead of using my class and hence built roles from DB. (I haven't yet gotten to implementation of this bit, just thinking in my head)

Comment: Don't know, signing the roles with a certificate is the first thing that comes to my mind. Could this be feasible for you?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm diving in uncharted territory right now. Not even sure how to do that. But I think thats a different question and for now I'm happy to accept your answer as THE answer :D Thank you so much for all the help. I'll do research and see where can I go with this further.